# Как правильно записать несколько byteBuffer в один файл

Tags: java, android, файлы

Подскажите как правильно последовательно записать несколько ByteBuffer в один txt файл. В отдельный файл один буфер я пишу так :

```
File file;
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
file = new File(path, "first.txt");
boolean append = true;
try {
    FileChannel wChannel = new FileOutputStream(file, append).getChannel();
    wChannel.write(byteBuffer);
    wChannel.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Как правильно в один txt файл последовательно записать несколько byteBuffer?

Answer (score 3):

Можно записывать, указывая сначала размер byteBuffer, потом сам byteBuffer. При чтении соответственно читать аналогично.

```
wChannel.write(byteBuffer.length);
wChannel.write(byteBuffer);
wChannel.write(byteBuffer2.length);
wChannel.write(byteBuffer2);
```

При чтении нужно будет считать позицию для чтения (Что-то вроде этого, это не код, а примерно как надо читать)

```
int index = 0;
int len = byteBuffer[index];
index++;
newBytes = wChannel.read(byteBuffer,index,len);
index+=len;
len = byteBuffer[index];
index++;
newBytes2 = wChannel.read(byteBuffer,index,len);
index+=len;
```